# how to reset function when value changes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

If event.title receives a new string even if the animation is in progress, I want animation to be interrupted and restarted with the new string (check if `(textWidth > $('#line2').width()`) for new string, width and copy are of the new string too).

```js
var testText = $('.test-text');

function wallpaperMediaPropertiesListener(event) {
  // event.title receives a random string at a random time.
  if (!event.title) {
    testText.text('\u200B');
  } else {
    testText.text(event.title);

    var textWidth = testText.outerWidth();
    let gapSize = 30;

    if (textWidth > $('#line2').width()) {
      var testTextCopy = $('<div></div>')
        .addClass('test-text-copy')
        .css({
          'margin-left': gapSize,
        })
        .insertAfter(testText)
        .text(testText.text());


      function animateText() {
        testText.delay(1000).animate({
          'margin-left': -(textWidth + gapSize)
        }, {
          duration: textWidth * 30,
          easing: 'linear',
          complete: function() {
            testText.css('margin-left', 0);
            animateText();
          }
        });
      }

      animateText();
    }
  }
}
window.wallpaperRegisterMediaPropertiesListener(wallpaperMediaPropertiesListener);
```

```css
#line2 {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1.4vh;
  width: 10vh;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  clip-path: inset(0% 0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="line2"><span class="test-text">this is the original text.</span></p>
```

Comment: I've convert to a snippet for you - it doesn't run due to missing function.  Please update so that we can see the issue, see [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

To reset the animation when the value changes, you can use the **stop** method to interrupt the ongoing animation and then restart it with the new string.

```
var testText = $('.test-text');
var animationInterval;

function wallpaperMediaPropertiesListener(event) {
  // event.title receives a random string at a random time.
  if (!event.title) {
    testText.text('\u200B');
  } else {
    if (animationInterval) {
      // If there is an ongoing animation, stop it
      testText.stop();
      clearInterval(animationInterval);
    }

    testText.text(event.title);

    var textWidth = testText.outerWidth();
    let gapSize = 30;

    if (textWidth > $('#line2').width()) {
      var testTextCopy = $('<div></div>')
        .addClass('test-text-copy')
        .css({
          'margin-left': gapSize,
        })
        .insertAfter(testText)
        .text(testText.text());

      function animateText() {
        animationInterval = setInterval(function() {
          testText.animate({ 'margin-left': -(textWidth + gapSize) }, {
            duration: textWidth * 30,
            easing: 'linear',
            complete: function() {
              testText.css('margin-left', 0);
            }
          });
        }, 1000);
      }

      animateText();
    }
  }
}

window.wallpaperRegisterMediaPropertiesListener(wallpaperMediaPropertiesListener);
```

**animationInterval** variable to keep track of the ongoing animation. When a new string is received, it checks if there's an ongoing animation (**animationInterval** is set) and stops it using **testText.stop()** and **clearInterval(animationInterval).** After that, it restarts the animation with the new string.

**Update**

The problem is that the textWidth and testTextCopy are not being correctly updated within the animation loop.

```
var testText = $('.test-text');
var animationInterval;

function wallpaperMediaPropertiesListener(event) {
  // event.title receives a random string at a random time.
  if (!event.title) {
    testText.text('\u200B');
  } else {
    if (animationInterval) {
      // If there is an ongoing animation, stop it
      testText.stop();
      clearInterval(animationInterval);
    }

    testText.text(event.title);

    var textWidth = testText.outerWidth();
    let gapSize = 30;

    if (textWidth > $('#line2').width()) {
      var testTextCopy = $('<div></div>')
        .addClass('test-text-copy')
        .css({
          'margin-left': gapSize,
        })
        .insertAfter(testText)
        .text(testText.text());

      function animateText() {
        testText.animate({ 'margin-left': -(textWidth + gapSize) }, {
          duration: textWidth * 30,
          easing: 'linear',
          step: function(now) {
            // Update text and width for each step of the animation
            var progress = now / -(textWidth + gapSize);
            var currentWidth = testText.outerWidth();
            textWidth = currentWidth > textWidth ? currentWidth : textWidth;
            testTextCopy.text(testText.text());
          },
          complete: function() {
            // Reset margin-left for the next cycle
            testText.css('margin-left', 0);

            // Restart the animation
            animateText();
          }
        });
      }

      // Add a delay before starting the animation
      setTimeout(function() {
        animateText();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
}

window.wallpaperRegisterMediaPropertiesListener(wallpaperMediaPropertiesListener);
```

You can use **requestAnimationFrame** for smoother control over the animation.

```
var testText = $('.test-text');
var animationFrame;
var animationStartTime;
var animationDuration = 3000; // Adjust the duration as needed
var animationDelay = 1000; // Delay before starting animation

function wallpaperMediaPropertiesListener(event) {
  if (!event.title) {
    testText.text('\u200B');
  } else {
    if (animationFrame) {
      // If there is an ongoing animation, cancel it
      cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
    }

    testText.text(event.title);

    var textWidth = testText.outerWidth();
    let gapSize = 30;

    if (textWidth > $('#line2').width()) {
      var testTextCopy = $('<div></div>')
        .addClass('test-text-copy')
        .css({
          'margin-left': gapSize,
        })
        .insertAfter(testText)
        .text(testText.text());

      function animateText(timestamp) {
        if (!animationStartTime) {
          animationStartTime = timestamp;
        }

        var progress = (timestamp - animationStartTime) / animationDuration;
        var marginLeft = -(progress * (textWidth + gapSize));

        testText.css('margin-left', marginLeft);

        if (progress < 1) {
          // Continue the animation
          animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animateText);
        } else {
          // Reset values for the next cycle
          testText.css('margin-left', 0);
          animationStartTime = null;

          // Restart the animation after a delay
          setTimeout(function() {
            animateText();
          }, animationDelay);
        }
      }

      // Start the animation after a delay
      setTimeout(function() {
        animateText();
      }, animationDelay);
    }
  }
}

window.wallpaperRegisterMediaPropertiesListener(wallpaperMediaPropertiesListener);
```

Comment: it doesnt work

the problem in the original script is:
When event.title receives a new string, testText value is updated even in the middle of the animation, but the animation does not end in the middle, but continues to the end. And even though the testText value is new, the textWidth and testTextCopy values remain the same as they were the first time.
If (textWidth > $('#line2').width()) is also checked only for the first string.

Im putting animateText() in the complete: function is because I wanna repeat animation.

Comment: @sheeta Thank you for the clarification. Now, please check again as I have updated the answer. hope it meet your requirement

Comment: still not working. problem remains the same. its not updating testTextCopy nor textWidth and not checking If (textWidth > $('#line2').width()) for new value.
I removed setTimeout and added .delay(1000) to original script. I want animation to pause for 1 sec in the beginning.

event.title gets the name of song that is currently playing. What I want to create is an animation that moves to the end of the string if the song title goes out of the frame, as it does in the music player. My code works if the testText value stays the same, but the moment I make it change, I get a lot of problems

Comment: My code doubles the string and places it at the end of the string with gap. when it goes out of bounds, Decrease the left margin of the first string until the position of the second string is at the position of the first one, and when it is, return the position of the first string to the beginning. This way we can animate to display string to the end and back to the beginning without animating second string.

Comment: @sheeta Thank you for the additional details. I see the issue now.  please check again i have update my answer

Comment: not working....

Comment: i try a different approach using requestAnimationFrame please check